# Change meta tag in header dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, dynamic

I'm creating a shareable connection with a button that the button I clicked before would execute a feature that modifies the OPEN GRAPH after it is posted to social media. I tried to click the button and share it with social media using shared APIs, but the title, link, thumbnail and description did not alter.

```js
const share = $("#change").click(()=>{
   $("meta[name=description]").remove();
   $("head").append("<meta name='description' content='new description'>" 
);})
```

Comment: What share APIs? Do they request the page based on a URL rather than reading from the user’s browser? Because that would both make sense and cause the problem.

Comment: You're right, I must be wrong implementing facebook share button. I use facebook share button, when user share a picture in my website, I want the user to get the picture(as thumbnail), description(as the description itself), title and so on. Like sharing an article link on facebook that has thumbnail, title, and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change meta tag using this

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('meta[name=description]').remove();
    $('head').append( '<meta name="description" content="this is new">' );
    console.log($('meta[name=description]').attr('content'));
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="description"content="this is old">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button>Change Meta</button>
```

Comment: What if I use facebook share button? I think, facebook restrict me for doing so. Or I am just wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach too

```js
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(){

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content);
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content = "this is new meta tag!";
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta name="description"content="this is old meta tag!">
</head>
<button id="mybutton">Modify</button>
```

Comment: How can I modify facebook share button using this code?